# How to delete a specific row from the table I created?

Tags: reactjs

After adding few rows in table with data. I am not able to remove the specific row. The row which is getting removed is always the last one. Need help where I am making mistake in delete method.

I have already create the remove row method but it is not working as expected

```
remove = (idx) =>{
  const rows = [...this.state.rows];
  rows.splice(idx,1);
  this.setState({ rows })
}
```

---

```
  <div>
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Id</th>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Number</th>
          </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
          {this.state.rows.map((item, idx) => (
            <tr key={idx}>
            <td>{idx}</td>
            <td><input
            type="text"
            name="name"
            ></input></td>
            <td><input
             type="text"
             name="number"
            ></input></td>
            <td><button onClick={()=>this.remove(idx)}>Remove</button></td>
          </tr>    
      ))}
          </tbody>
    </table>
    <button onClick={this.add}>Add</button>
  </div>
```

after adding 3 rows for e.g with data. If I click on remove from 2nd row. The same should be removed. Not the last one.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this issue by binding idx with onClick as below code. Reason last get removed is idx value which would be used by onClick would be last idx.

```
<div>
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Id</th>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Number</th>
          </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
          {this.state.rows.map((item, idx) => (
            <tr key={idx}>
            <td>{idx}</td>
            <td><input
            type="text"
            name="name"
            ></input></td>
            <td><input
             type="text"
             name="number"
            ></input></td>
            <td><button onClick={this.remove.bind(null, idx)}>Remove</button></td>
          </tr>    
      ))}
          </tbody>
    </table>
    <button onClick={this.add}>Add</button>
  </div>
```

-------- Edit --------------

```
remove = (idx) =>{
  const rows = this.state.rows;
  rows.splice(idx,1);
  this.setState({ rows });
}
```

Comment: I have tried the above solution. But it is not working.

Comment: @lakshya If it has solved your problem please give me upvote. Thanks.